# Get phone call duration info in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using **CordovaCallNumberPlugin** plugin to connect call through ionic.
This plugin is working fine for me but by this plugin I am not able to get call duration and their is no event fired when call is hangup.

I tried to get call log from phone history and then find out call duration but that is not proper way to follow.

So can any one please help me with any plugin or any suitable code.

```
window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber success, error, phone_number, true
```

this code I am using for calling through list.

Answer (score 0):

That plugin does not have any phone event call, but maybe you could use another one in conjunction with it:

https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap

This plugin is available only for Android devices and expose these events:

- "RINGING": phone is ringing
- "OFFHOOK": phone occupied by call
- "IDLE": no call activity

So if the current state is idle and the previous state was ringing, they cancelled the call. If the current state is offhook and the previous state was ringing, they answered the call.

Comment: This reply solve my problem in android but i am still stuck in IOS as i am developing app for both os i cannot use this plugin.

Comment: Sorry but I have never heard of a sort of plugin for phone call management on iOS...